# Java: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'

Tags: java, html, xml

Using JAVA, I am getting below error:

```
[Fatal Error] loose.dtd:31:3: The declaration for the entity "HTML.Version" must end with '>'.
```

on parsing one of HTML having below content on top:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
```

Comment: just leave <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: The error is not inside your code or your html - [the linked .dtd file](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd) is broken. Take a look at it and you can confirm what the error message says. Unfortunately I have no idea how to fix the broken file - can you modify your html data? Or disable the validation against the dtd?

Comment: Thing is: you are not showing any of your java code around that. So what exactly do you expect from our side? In addition to that: is it relevant that you are using java ...

Comment: If you are trying to parse an SGML DTD like the HTML 4 DTD with an XML parser then that is not going to work, you will need to use an HTML parser or SGML parser to parse SGML based HTML.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped to disable dtd load and validation like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```